# node net socket connection timeout

Tags: node.js, sockets, timeout

I noticed, that my node server's net.createConnection() has a very long timeout before firing an error on some occasions (seems to be a particular problem with ports...)

i tried to connect to somedomain:9000  (listening, connecting and working as expected)
and to somedomain:1234 (same domain, different port, waiting around 2 minutes until "connect ETIMEDOUT")

When i connect to non-existent domains, i get an error right away, but not if i connect to unreachable ports on reachable hosts.
i need to determine if a machine is reachable in <1sec..

how do i handle this? Must be some way to notice an unreachable port in under 2minutes?
at least some kind of timeout that just sets the address as unreachable after a set amout of time?

Thanks

UPDATE: current Connection code:

```
this.openConnection = function() {
    try {
        console.log("[INFO] connecting to " + device.ip + ":" + device.port);
        device.clientSocket = new net.createConnection(this.port,this.ip)
            .on('connect', device.connected)
            .on('data', device.inputReceived)
            .on('error', function(err) {

                if (err.code == "ENOTFOUND") {
                    console.log("[ERROR] No device found at this address!");
                    device.clientSocket.destroy();
                    return;
                }

                if (err.code == "ECONNREFUSED") {
                    console.log("[ERROR] Connection refused! Please check the IP.");
                    device.clientSocket.destroy();
                    return;
                }


                console.log("[CONNECTION] Unexpected error! " + err.message + "     RESTARTING SERVER");


                process.exit(1);

            })
            .on('disconnect', function() {
                console.log("[CONNECTION] disconnected!");
            });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("[CONNECTION] connection failed! " + err);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you connect, you can just set your own timer for whatever timeout you want and if the connect has not succeeded when that timer fires, then it did not succeed as quickly as you want.

This could be encapsulated in a single function with a single callback or returning a promise.

---

Based on your code, here's a shot at adding a timeout to it (untested code):

```
this.openConnection = function(timeout) {
    var timer;
    timeout = timeout || 2000;
    try {
        console.log("[INFO] connecting to " + device.ip + ":" + device.port);
        device.clientSocket = new net.createConnection(this.port,this.ip)
            .on('connect', function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                device.connected();
            })
            .on('data', function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                device.inputReceived();
            })
            .on('error', function(err) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                if (err.code == "ENOTFOUND") {
                    console.log("[ERROR] No device found at this address!");
                    device.clientSocket.destroy();
                    return;
                }

                if (err.code == "ECONNREFUSED") {
                    console.log("[ERROR] Connection refused! Please check the IP.");
                    device.clientSocket.destroy();
                    return;
                }


                console.log("[CONNECTION] Unexpected error! " + err.message + "     RESTARTING SERVER");


                process.exit(1);

            })
            .on('close', function() {
                console.log("[CONNECTION] disconnected!");
            });
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("[ERROR] Attempt at connection exceeded timeout value");
            device.clientSocket.end();
        }, timeout);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("[CONNECTION] connection failed! " + err);
    }
};
```

Comment: i need to set a flag that shows the user if this device is on- or offline. how would you do this exactly? a promise wouldn't work, i guess, because i don't know beforehand what the status is gonna be and it can't be wrong.
just a simple setTimeout?

Comment: @PaulSchneider - show me your current code for connecting where you detect the failure to connect and I can show you how to adapt it to add your own timer.

Comment: @PaulSchneider - I've added a version with a timeout in it.

Comment: not gonna be able to test it until saturday.. maybe tomorrow. i'll let you know, thanks :)

Comment: ok i tried it. doesn't quite work as it should. the socket gets closed, even if the connection does work.
as far as i understand, the timer disconnects, if it has not been cleared by any of the connect etc events.
but it seems not to work, i have also tried using a higher timeout
[INFO] connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
[INFO] Device 4 @ xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx connected!
[INFO] Device is ONLINE
[ERROR] Connection attempt timed out after 5s
[CONNECTION] Unexpected error! This socket is closed.     RESTARTING SERVER

any ideas? thanks :)

Comment: @PaulSchneider - have you looked into the problem to figure out which code path causes the socket to close?  I just took your shell of functionality and added the timeout.  If the code goes through the `.on('connect', ...)` or the `.on('data', ...)` path, then the timeout will be removed and no longer in effect so it will just be your regular code in play.

Comment: @PaulSchneider - where does this message "Connection attempt timed out after 5s [CONNECTION]" come from?  That is not in the code I recommended so I'm wondering where that comes from?

Comment: i added the section with the "after 5s" myself, to have a prettier output. it is essentially your message in var timer.
and concerning your other comment: that's why i'm confused myself. as the console says (and i can control the device, so the connection DOES work and the messages ARE printed, so that function MUST have run), everything is working fine. except the timer doesn't seem to be reset :/

Comment: @PaulSchneider - it's a typo in the code.  Everywhere it says `clearTimeout(timeout);`, it should be `clearTimeout(timer);`,  I corrected the code in my answer.

Comment: it works now! i had to change inputReceived() to inputReceived(data), but now it's working :) thanks very much!

Comment: I can't find any documentation that indicates there's actually a `disconect` event. Looks like `end` or `close` would be the closest things. I know this is an old thread, but even looking back as far as 0.10.x I only see `end` and `close`.

Comment: @redbmk - Yes, that appears to be the case for a generic socket object.  Other types of sockets (like socket.io) do have such an event.  The `disconnect` event handler came from the OP's code so I just left it in place in my answer.  I'll edit my answer to use `close`.